# What is the value of this Composit Definite

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose $f(x)=x^3-{\frac32}x^2+x+{\frac14}$ then what is the value of $\int_0^1 f^{2022}(x)dx$ where $f^n(x)=f•f•...•f(x)$(n times)
$$A)2022^{3/2}$$
$$B)0$$
$$C)2022$$
D)None of the above
This is from a MCQ mock test problem for IIT-JEE entrance test.
My intuition tells me $ \exists m$ such that $f^m(x)=f(x)$ there is some fixed point but this seems bit lengthy. For any easy way of solving this or any suggestions would be highly valued. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes composition

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) = x^3 + \frac14 x$ and note that $f(x) = g\left(x - \frac 12\right) + \frac12$. It is then clear that $f^n (x) = g^n\left(x - \frac 12\right)+ \frac12$. Now note that $g$ is odd, and hence that $g^n$ is odd.
The integral then becomes
$$\int_{-\frac 12}^{\frac 12} g^{2022}(x) + \frac 12dx = \int_{-\frac 12}^{\frac 12}\frac12 dx =\frac12$$

Comment: Thanks but I didn't get it. How did you get $f^n (x) = f(x)$?? There's nothing in the question like that. If you please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It doesn't